# How to export save game?

Tags: the-gold-factory

I'm trying to "export" my game as text to use the 'Import' feature in The Gold Factory.

[image]

Clicking the `Save game as text` button appears to do nothing. Should I be seeing some text on screen or something added to my clipboard?

I'm using Chrome on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The save game text should show up as a message window at the top of the page. There appears to be a bug where this doesn't show up. Simply save the game using the `Save game` button to save as HTML5 local storage, then refresh the page.

Refreshing the page should now make the `Save game as text` button work as intended. A popup at the top of the window will display the save text to be used with the `Load game` option.

[image]